# TestNG dataproviders with a @BeforeClass

Tags: java, testng

I am trying to run a class with multiple tests under two different conditions. Basically I have a bunch of tests related to a search. I am adding new functionality of a new search strategy, and in the meantime want to run the already written tests under both configurations. As we have multiple classes each with multiple tests I want to streamline this process as much as possible. Ideally it'd be great to do the setup in a @BeforeClass with a data provider so that all tests in the class are basically run twice under the different configurations, but doesn't look like this is possible.

Right now I have:

```
public class SearchTest1 {
    @Test(dataProvider = "SearchType")
    public void test1(SearchType searchType) {
        setSearchType(searchType);
        //Do the test1 logic
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "SearchType")
    public void test2(SearchType searchType) {
        setSearchType(searchType);
        //Do the test2 logic
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "SearchType")
    public Object[][] createData() {
        return new Object[][]{
            new Object[] {SearchType.scheme1, SearchType.scheme2}
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This looks like a pretty good way for me. Except I'd move the data provider in its own class, so everyone can reference the same one.

Comment: That's actually how it's arranged. I wrote it this way to make it easier to read here. I should mention that there are ~20 classes with a total of 268 tests. I'd like to avoid writing these lines in all 268 of these locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to annotate each and every method with the data provider, you can use a `Factory` instead.

```
public class SearchTest1 {
    private final SearchType searchType;

    public SearchTest1( SearchType searchType ) {
       this.searchType = searchType;
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        //Do the test2 logic
    }
    ...
}
```

And your factory class will be:

```
public class SearchTestFactory {
   @Factory
   public Object [] createInstances() {
      return new Object[] { new SeartchTest1( SearchType.ONE ), new SearchTest1( SearchType.TWO ) };
   }
}
```

*See more on this [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories).*

Then you can either have one factory that enumerates every test class or a separate factory for each, the first one is obviously less flexible, the second one means slightly more code.

Comment: So this really means making a constructor for each of these classes and pass in the type. That works I think. Also I found this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection] which points to a way to enumerate all the classes in this package to keep the amount of code minimal.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice addition, although I'd probably combine the package scanning with the `MethodAnnotationsScanner` scanner from the Reflections library to return only classes that contain methods annotated with `@Test`.

Comment: But that will return a set of methods. Would that mean going through each method and adding their class to the list to instantiate? Or is there a way to filter by that with reflections?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used the Reflections library so I can't really answer whether it can do that, but manually building up a set of classes from the methods doesn't sound too complicated either.

Comment: That may not work if using PowerMock; see https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/925

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameters in @BeforeClass. Just use (with some cleanup)

> context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameters()

```java
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
      @BeforeClass
      public void setUp(ITestContext context) {
          System.out.println(context.getCurrentXmlTest().getAllParameters());
      }
```